# Inverse Laplace transform through contour integration

Tags: contour-integration, singularity, inverse-laplace, branch-points

$$
F(s)=\frac{\sin(s)}{\sqrt{s}}
$$
Does the inverse laplace transform of this function exist?
But how do we find this through contour integration?
Any suggestions please.
Because as this is special case in Bromwich contour.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: They tried to ask the question here !

Comment: This is new to me, I know about about $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}$$

Comment: As it has different branch points. But how can find poles of this function.

Comment: I am thinking that there is no inverse laplace transform for this function. Could you please elaborate. Because I am unable to evaluate higher oder Bromwich. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this has no inverse Laplace Transform since $\sin(s)$ has exponential growth along the Bromwich contour in the upper half plane.

Comment: How can I represent in formal way! Could you please tell me!